# Fly America compliant itineraries only

Tags: air-travel, bookings, ita-matrix

I need to follow the [Fly America Act](https://www.gsa.gov/policy-regulations/policy/travel-management-policy/fly-america-act) to book upcoming international travel.

Is there a way to specifically search for compliant itineraries through [ITA Flight Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/)? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

ITA allows you to specify the list of airlines to consider, like Destination airport: `IAD :: UA,AA,DL`

There is - as far as I know - no way to specify ‘Fly American’ directly, but once you collect the airlines codes in a string, you can save this string in a text file and reuse it every time.

See for example https://www.travelcodex.com/advanced-routing-language-in-ita/ for an explanation with examples.

Comment: Note that Fly America is a little more complicated than just flying on a list of approved airlines; after all, U.S. airlines serve relatively little of the world. There are circumstances, for example, that allow a federal traveler to use a foreign carrier if use of a U.S. carrier would more than double the travel time, or if the U.S. carrier flights would require departing or arriving between midnight and 6am.

Comment: In addition, a number of foreign airlines based in countries with open skies agreements are also exempted.  This apparently includes many European, Japanese and Australian airlines.

Comment: And all the code-shares with U.S. carriers count. My last Fly America ticket was through Delta, with the flight run by China South. I got to pay more than 2x the China South rate for the privilege of 'flying' Delta...

Comment: Well, @JonCuster, at least the money went to the chinese owners of an _American_ company, not to the chinese owners of a chinese company.